# Is there a function $f : D^2 \setminus 0 \to R$ such that $f(x) x \to 0$ but $f(x)$ not bounded near $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I just showed that, for $f$ holomorphic on the punctured disc, $zf(z) \to 0$ implies that $f$ has a removable singularity at $0$. This in turn implies that $|f(z)|$ is bounded near 0. (The other implication is obvious.)

My argument relied heavily on a function $g(z)$ being itself holomorphic ($g(z) = zf(z)$ for $z \not = 0$, $g(z) = 0$ at $0$), which followed from the holomorphicity of $f(z)z$ on $D^2 \setminus 0$.

Therefore, I am curious to know if there exists a non-holomorphic but real differentiable function on the punctured disc, $f : D^2 \setminus 0 \to R$ with the property that $xf(x) \to 0$, but $f(x)$ is not bounded near 0.

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lvert z\rvert}}$ is real-differentiable.

Comment: @DanielFischer Wonderful, thank you. And the analogue $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}$ would not represent a complex differentiable counter example because the logarithm cannot be defined in the punctured disc?

Comment: Yes, $0$ is a branch point of $\sqrt{z}$ (and $\log z$), so you can't even define a continuous square root on the punctured disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function 
$$f: z \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{ |z|}}$$
is real-differentiable, but not complex differentiable, away from $0$.
Clearly, $zf(z) \to 0$ as $z \to 0$, but $f$ is not bounded near $0$.
So being holomorphic is somehow distinguished.

---

*This answer is pulled from [the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/841014/is-there-a-function-f-d2-setminus-0-to-r-such-that-fx-x-to-0-but-f#comment1735473_841014). I added this answer to remove it from the unanswered queue, as the system continually bumps old open unanswered questions to the front. It is CW --- anyone can edit this answer.*